# Compute md5 checksum for file in Microsoft Power Automate or Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps, checksum, power-automate

What is the recommended approach to compute a file checksum from a Microsoft Flow or Azure Logic Apps?

Here I need MD5 checksum but it would be interesting to know for other standard algorithms as well, such as SHA variants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this requirement, I suggest you to [create an azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-app-portal) and implement it in function code. Then you can [call the function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions#add-existing-functions-to-logic-apps) in your logic app. Here is a [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/60b4cccd-7f0f-4b36-bc8a-8ada43274e81/simple-way-to-calculate-the-hash-eg-sha256-of-a-file-in-a-logic-apps-step?forum=azurelogicapps) similar with your requirement.

And for your requirement be implemented directly in logic app, you can also vote up for this feature on azure [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/18956275-add-checksum-to-file-connector) page.